# Need help regarding deploying a typescript based node server to vercel

Tags: typescript, deployment, configuration, vercel, custom-error-pages

I am constantly getting a `Code: NOT_FOUND` error on my server running endpoint.

Its mostly a configuration setup issue for a typescript based node server. Its been quite long I am struggling this issue.

Also the deployment summary never ends running:[image: deployment summary]

Here is my server directory file structer:

```
Server
   ├─ .env
   ├─ dist
   │  ├─ index.js
   │  └─ model
   │     └─ topic.js
   ├─ index.ts
   ├─ model
   │  └─ topic.ts
   ├─ package-lock.json
   ├─ package.json
   ├─ tsconfig.json
   └─ vercel.json
```

vercel.json

```json
{
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "dist/index.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node",
            "config": { "includeFiles": ["dist/**"] }
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "dist/index.js"
        }
    ]
  }
```

`package.json` configurations that i half understood from some random blogs

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./dist/index.js",
    "build": "npx tsc",
    "ts.check": "tsc --project tsconfig.json",
    "add-build": "git add dist",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npx tsc --watch\" \"nodemon dist/index.js\""
  },
  "pre-commit": [
    "ts.check",
    "build",
    "add-build"
  ],
```

Error:
[image]

Everything's working fine in my local usage of server. Although not very aware of how exactly to resolve out the typescript server deployment. This is far different from a normal node javascript based express server deployment

Answer (score 0):

```
//tsconfig.json
"outDir": "./dist"
```

make sure to comment out this line in .gitignore file.

```
.gitignore
# dist
```